# Error when looping through an associative array in PHP

Tags: php

I get the following error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in  on line 37
>   0: Array

When trying to run the following:

```
while($allOrders = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $orderName = $allOrders["order_name"];
    $orderId = $allOrders["id"];
    $orders[] = array($orderName => $orderId);
}
foreach ($orders as $orderName1 => $orderId1) {
    echo("".$orderName1.": ".$orderId1."");
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that the code did not format correctly

Comment: You have a multidimensional array! So you need 2 foreach loops! Do `print_r($orders);` and you will see what I mean

Comment: @pennst8: Take a look on my answer, you shouldn't loop twice on orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Correct way to loop orders:

```
$all_orders = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($all_orders as $order) {
echo $order["order_name"].": ".$order["id"];
}
```

Comment: Assuming the ID is unique, and name may not be, I would use $orders[$orderId] = $orderName; and foreach ($orders as $orderId => $orderName) {...}

Answer (score 0):

As @Rizier123 correctly states, you are trying to `foreach ()` through the top level of a multidimensional array. Your MySQLi query will return a `$results` array with an embedded level of arrays. If you think of your `$results` in terms of MySQL rows and cells, you're looping through `$results` to each `$row` but should also be looping through each `$row`'s many `$cell`s.

Try this

```
foreach ($result as $row => $rowvalue) { // now $row is the row name in the array, and $rowvalue is the individal row array itself
    // some work
    foreach ($rowvalue as $cell => $cellvalue) { // now $cell is the cell name in the array, and $cellvalue is the cell value string itself
        // display your cell names and values
        echo "" . $cell . ": " . $cellvalue . "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you get this warning or error when you are trying to get the value of an array as a string. This say that you have multidimensional array, but you are trying get the value of the child array as a string. Try at first this command `print_r($variable)` to check the real output of your variable. You can loop inside and array also like this:

```
foreach($orders as $order)
{
 echo $order->orderId. " | ". $order->orderName;
}
```

Must of time it's how i do when i need this loop for my model. But usually i use ORM in a framework. May be i can be use in your case also !